# Удаление записи через заданное время

Tags: mysql, sql

Реально ли сделать так, чтобы любая запись добавленная в таблицу, через, к примеру, 15 секунд удалялась сама? Если да, то подскажите в каком направлении искать, спасибо

Уточнение: за каждой записью должен быть таймер, я так понимаю, не нужно делать так, чтобы все записи удалились каждые 15 сек

Comment: CRON. Если используете ROR, то смотрите в сторону Active Job.

Comment: А нет. Кроном можно удалять раз в 15 минут, но не через 15 минут после создания.

Comment: @Mike идея с удалением устаревших записей мне понравилась, я ведь смогу указать, после какого срока запись можно считать устаревшей? Еще хотелось бы получить краткую подсказку, как это реализовать и что гуглить. На данном этапе я владею только навыками отправки простых запросов, поэтому мне нужно немного конкретики, спасибо!

Comment: Если вам важно, чтобы устаревшие записи никогда не попадались, вам скорее стоит добавить в запросы условие на "не старше 15 секунд" (можно даже инкапсулировать эту деталь в **представление** [см. `CREATE VIEW`]), а периодически чистить лишние записи. Хотя я не знаю, насколько MySQL в этом силён. И вообще мне кажется, что MySQL не очень подходит для подобных краткоживущих данных.

Comment: @Кнопкатык спасибо, приму к сведению. Если не MySQL, то что тогда посоветуете?

Comment: Очень мало данных, чтобы однозначно советовать. MySQL сгодится, если вам при этом важны гарантии согласованности и долговечности. Если нет, можно поискать что-то более легковесное и менее надёжное. Ведь даже если произойдёт моментный косяк в данных, через 15 секунд его не станет. Если подаваться в крайности, то хоть in-memory структуры данных демона, который занимается обслуживанием запросов со стороны.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну отчего же `mysql` сам так не сможет? Сможет, у него есть [`event scheduler`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html).

Включая варианты из комментариев, все они реализуются одинаково: вам необходимо сделать поле с датой добавление (заполнять поле может mysql тоже самостоятельно):

```
timestamp not null default current_timestamp
```

Затем любым удобным способом дёргать

```
delete from tablename where added_at < now() - interval 15 second
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в запись поле типа `datetime`. Это будет или текущая дата или дата "устаревания" записи. Если в момент создания/модификации записи время ее жизни уже известно, то пишите сразу в нее текущее время плюс время жизни.

```
insert into table(col1, col2, life_time)
values("aaa","xxx",now() + interval 15 second);
```

В любом удобном месте, например перед использованием еще не устаревших удалять старые:

delete from table where life_time

Или можно и дольше оставлять их в базе, например для истории, предусмотрев в  выборке актуальных записей условие `life_time < now()`