# Автоматическое удаление записей MySQL, через заданное время

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет, помогите разобраться, почему у меня не удаляются записи из БД через заданное время? Много гуглил, но безрезультатно..

У меня есть вот такой запрос:

```
$del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE `time` < now() - interval 30 sec");
```

Вот такая таблица:

```
ALTER TABLE `messages` CHANGE `time` `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Но БД не чистится, в чем проблема?

Comment: Замените 'DELETE' на 'SELECT *' и проверьте есть ли результат. Если есть значит проблема или в констрейнтах БД или ошибка в php коде, если же результата нету, то смотрите данные таблицы.

Comment: _Всегда_ предусматривайте в программе обработку и вывод сообщений об ошибках базы данных. Если бы вы это сделали, то увидели бы, что MySQL вам возвращает ошибку синтаксиса, по той причине, что единицы измерения времени `sec` не существует, есть `second`

Comment: *У меня есть вот такой запрос* Это не запрос, а PHP-код. А запрос в этом коде синтаксически неверен - MySQL не знает о существовании единицы измерения интервала `sec`.

Comment: Я сделал согласно инструкции https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533106

Comment: @Владислав А надо было ещё и в документацию заглянуть. Вот сюда: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все заработало, нужно было sec заменить на second, спасибо всем кто помогал

```
$del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE `time` < now() - interval 30 second");
```